# Comment is undefined - Where am I doing mistake?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am trying to create a createcomment function in controller file. Here is my function

```
  $scope.createComment = function() {
            console.log("comment is: ", $scope.commentText);
            Task.createComment({taskId: $scope.task._id, content: $scope.commentText}).then(function(data) {
                console.log("createComment Data is: ", data);


            }, function(err) {
                console.log("Got an error: ", err);
            })
        }
```

And here is my view code.

```
 <div class="form-group col-lg-12 p-init m-b-25">
                <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" cols="56" name="comment" id="zenplan_comment" placeholder="Write a Comment ..." ng-model="commentText"></textarea>
                <button type="button" class="btn add_txt" ng-click="createComment()">Add</button>
              </div>
```

But when I try to add/create a comment, it shows that comment is undefined.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: actually it's a very large project. I'm using api server and ui server separately so it would be very difficult to create its jsfiddle. Sorry.

Comment: Or Can you please suggest me that how can I make its jsfiddle?

Comment: can you change textarea for input for a while, to see if maybe thats an issue?

Comment: or make createComment a function with parameter (commentText), and see what happens then?

Comment: replacing textarea with input also gives same issue

Comment: if you check jsfiddle I;ve provided, you can see that everything is fine

Comment: do you use commentText in any other place in your html?

Comment: No, I'm not using commentText anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have everything like you've described, it should be working:

http://jsfiddle.net/dLnnLbx5/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.createComment = function() {
            console.log("comment is: ", $scope.commentText);
        }
}
```

Comment: yeah, it works here fine. But I'm still getting error. What do you think, where can be error? in directives? or in anyother file?